# Error produced with datetime class function

Tags: python, class, datetime, dictionary, key-value

I'm writing a function in python 3 that consumes a photo-dir-entry-list (pdel) and produces a dictionary of type photo-name-dict where the key is the filename of the photo and the values are objects of type Photo with the field size having the size of the element in the photo-dir-entry and the field pdate having the date of the element from the photo-dir-entry. The function I've written is producing an error:

```
 ## A photo-dir-entry is a list consisting of the following
 ## elements in order:
 ## - a Str representing the filename of the photo
 ## - an Int[>=1] representing the size of the photo file
 ## - an Int representing the year the photo was taken
 ## - an Int[1<=,<=12] representing the month the photo was taken
 ## - an Int[1<=,<=31] representing the day the photo was taken
 ## The Date elements contain a valid date.

 ## A photo-dir-entry-list is a list of photo-dir-entries with unique filenames.

 ## A Photo is an object consisting of two fields
 ## - size: an Int[>0] representing the size of the file
 ## - pdate: a Date representing the date the photo was taken    
 class Photo:
     'Fields: size, pdate'

 ## Purpose: constructor for class Photo
 ## __init__: Int Int Int Int -> Photo
 ## Note: Function definition needs a self parameter and does not require a return statement
def __init__(self, size, year, month, day):
    self.size = size
    self.pdate = date(year, month, day)

 ## Purpose: Produces a string representation of a Photo
 ## __repr__: Photo -> Str
def __repr__(self):
    s1 = "SIZE: " + str(self.size)
    s2 = "; DATE: " + self.pdate.isoformat()
    return s1 + s2

def create_photo_name_dict(pdel):
    ph_dict = {}
    for entry in pdel:
        ph_dict[entry[0]] = Photo(ph_dict[entry[1]], ph_dict[entry[2]],  ph_dict[entry[3]], ph_dict[entry[4]])
    return ph_dict
```

When I call the function:

```
create_photo_name_dict([["DSC315.JPG",55,2011,11,13],
                        ["DSC316.JPG",53,2011,11,12]])
```

I end up with an error where I should be producing

```
{ "DSC315.JPG": Photo(55,2011,11,13),
         "DSC316.JPG": Photo(53,2011,11,12)}
```

The error is:

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Wing101.app/Contents/Resources/src/debug/tserver/_sandbox.py", line 2, in <module>
if __name__ == '__main__':
  File "/Applications/Wing101.app/Contents/Resources/src/debug/tserver/_sandbox.py", line 56, in create_photo_name_dict
builtins.KeyError: 55`
```

Comment: And the error is...?

Comment: `an error`? do you think you could be even less specific?

Comment: what do you expect `ph_dict[entry[1]]` to do, exactly?

Comment: I expect it to take the datetime module data structure its consuming and convert it into a dictionary

Answer (score 1):

In your `create_photo_name_dict()` , while creating the dict in the `for` loop , you are trying to pass in arguments to `Photo` as `ph_dict[entry[1]]` , etc. But ph_dict is initially empty, so this would never work (And pretty sure this is not what you want either.

Just send in `entry[1]` , `entry[2] , etc as it is , I believe that is what you want as well -

```
ph_dict[entry[0]] = Photo(entry[1], entry[2],  entry[3], entry[4])
```